# Why is this CSS loaded with MIME type "text/troff"?

Tags: html, css, mime-types

I add my CSS file in the header of my HTML file via

```
<link href="project.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When opening the page in Inspect mode on FF I can see in the console that

```
The stylesheet https://example.com/project.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/troff", is not "text/css".
```

The file itself is very standard (the presence or absence of the comment on top does not change anything - I tried that to hint that this is a CSS file)

```
/*!
CSS for project
*/

#devices {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

(...)
```

In the same header, Bootstrap is loaded correctly:

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Is there something specific I should do to have the MIME type recognized correctly?**

Comment: Is your server set up to serve the mime type (not sure if this affects externally loaded files)?

Comment: You need to tell us what server you're using if you want help setting up the server to serve CSS with the correct MIME type.

Comment: @Pete @MikeMcCaughan - these are good points, I was under the impression that `type="text/css"`would be enough to tell the browser the MIME type. I do not directly control the web server but I will have this fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was under the impression that `type="text/css"` would be enough to tell the browser the MIME type.

It does tell the browser what MIME type it can expect the linked resource to be, which is why the error says "its MIME type [...] is not 'text/css'.", but it doesn't promise that the server will actually supply a resource of that MIME type. That's up to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Because of a security issue it is not enough to set style sheet "rel" tag type property to text/css, you should set content type in http headers(content-type:text/css), the question is old but in case another person have this problem in IIS and see this page: go to control panel -> programs and features -> turn windows features on or off -> internet information services -> world wide web services -> common http features -> static content, enable this option and restart your IIS.